# multi-touch for programs that don't support it

Tags: autohotkey, touchscreen, 3d-modeling

I have a touchscreen that I'd like to use with a 3d modeling program. I think that I could be more productive in a 3d environment if I could use touch to navigate in this program but unfortuanatly multi-touch isn't supported.

Can I fake it using a program similar to autohotkey? I don't expect to get multiple cursors or anything crazy but it would be great if I could pinch to zoom (centered at the point between the two fingers) or interpret a swipe or gesture as a keyboard shortcut. Basically intercept the touchscreen input and translate it to commands the program understands.

Has anyone found a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a third party app to do this.

[TouchMe Gesture Studio](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.microsoft.com%2Fwindows%2Fen-us%2Fapp%2Ftouchme-gesture-studio%2F740d3578-ddb4-4f74-b489-5a3782cb7607&ei=6SdHVOKZEZGAygSS9AE&usg=AFQjCNF9D2QzNXH8iN1J1cbwh513ULr9tA&sig2=SGC9yz7CzGjDYN4mQ7XtxQ) may be able to help, it will let you assign touchscreen gestures to hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may well be possible, but probably not with AutoHotKey, as I recall that a few years ago someone showed me a Windows 7 touch-screen tablet, and he had non-touch-screen aware OpenGL software running on it, with full touch capability. (I know the software wasn't touch-aware, as I wrote it!)

In this case, the manufacturer of the tablet had provided software that converted on-screen clicks and drags into the right kinds of mouse movements for non-aware software.

So, I just googled for 'touch screen monitor software', and there are quite a few hits to trawl through. Some appear to be specific to manufacturers of particular systems, such as [Elo TouchSystems](http://www.elotouch.com/Support/Downloads/dnld.asp).

I'd suggest, therefore, that you look at the support website for your brand of display, to see if they provide any tools/drivers.